# Ldap(s) authentication in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ldap

I am trying to make ldap authentication through a secure Ldaps sever in Xamarin Forms. It uses a CA root certificate. I can make none secure standard ldap authentication with cleartext user and password with below code without any problem. But our company changed ldap servers to ldaps servers. So they want us to use CA root certificate and make secure connection to ldaps. I couldn't find any sample code for Xamarin Forms to make secure ldaps connection and authentication with root certificate. How can i convert my code to make this connection with CA root certificate.

```
void ldap_check() {
    cn.Connect("209.132.219.125", 389); //636 ssl

    try
    {
        cn.Bind("uid=adam,ou=People,dc=localdomain,dc=local", "3923dEf!fde1");
        Console.WriteLine("::: LDAP success" + cn.ToString() + " ::: ");
    }
    catch (LdapException f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LDAP FAIL : " + f.ResultCode.ToString());
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LDAP FAIL : " + f.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: For now, i do not find the official document for the Ldaps. You could post your requirement in the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Openned the requirement :  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14627

Comment: Let us follow this topic.